# How to remove .php extensions without changing all links

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

How I can do to remove .php extension (and html if it's possible in all link) without changing all links ?
I have search and I have found this solution :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It's work good but there are a problem, in fact in my header (or all post form), my link looks like this :

```
<a href="action.php">Action</a>
```

So then users click on, the url is :

```
mysite.com/action.php
```

How I can do to all my url don't have .php exentison without changing all links in my website

Thank you

Comment: `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Comment: this might be useful https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 3):

This will Work

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

On apache 2.4 and later, END flag is used to prevent infinite loop error.

Comment: I'm not saying your code will not work, but can you explain to OP, why did you use `[NC,END]` instead of `[NC,L]` and why is OP's code behaves the way it does.

Comment: On apache 2.4 and later, END flag is used  to  prevent infinite loop error.

Comment: Thanks, please add that to your answer, so that Op and other people with similar issue can learn from it

Comment: Good it's work ! But in localhost I have this : http://localhost/action but I want http://localhost/mysite/action, how I can do ? thank you

Comment: Replace last line with
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,END]

Comment: I have add this in my htacess : RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,END] but I still had locahost/action

Comment: Good answer, +1